# Error handling ajax call from asp mvc controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I cannot manage to get my desired error handling:

An AJAX call is run from the browser. It fires an Action in the controller. 
If everything is ok in the Action it should go to the `.done()` section. In other case it should continue in the `.fail()`

In my case, it always enters into the `.done()`
I would like to be able to execute the code within the `.fail()` callback when catching an exception in the controller.

I have tried with a `HttpStatusCodeResult` or a simply propagation with `throw` but it always follows through the `.done()`

**HTML-JAVASCRIPT**

```
function OnSelectedGraphicChanged() {
    var selectedGraphic = SelectedGraphic.GetValue();
    var url = '/GraphicDesigner/GenerateGraphic';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        data: {
            graphic: selectedGraphic
        },
    }).done(function (result) {
        debugger;
        if (!result.error) {
            // do some stuff
        }
        ChartLoadingPanel.Hide();
    }).fail(function (result) {
        // handle errors
        debugger;
        //do some stuff
        location.href = "/Home/"
    });
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult GenerateGraphic(int graphic)
{
    try
    {
        // do some stuff

        return Json(new
        {
            error = false,
            exception = false,
            graphic = RenderHelper.RenderViewToString(this.ControllerContext, "Graphic/_displayChart", model),
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500, "Unexpected error");
        //throw;
    }
}
```

**GLOBAL.ASAX.CS**

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception exception = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError();
    //TODO: Handle Exception
    Session.Clear();
    Server.ClearError();
}
```

Comment: try removing  `Server.ClearError();`

Comment: @KhanhTO It made no difference.